# JPA Column does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity `B` which contains a map of entities `<VC, P>` in which some of the fields in `P`, e.g. `A` is not being linked with my join table and gives the error:

> PSQLException: ERROR: column pricing1_.pricing_a does not exist

I am trying to make it such that when I persist my main entity, `B`, that all of the entities in my map will also be persisted as well (if possible) all in one go.

This error occurs both when I do

```
bRepo.save(b);
```

and

```
pRepo.saveAll(b.getPricing().values()); // by here the values at least exists in its own table (p)
bRepo.save(b);
```

here is what I have

Main entity B

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(
          name = "b_p",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_name", referencedColumnName = "name"))
  @MapKeyJoinColumns({
          @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "p_c"),
          @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "c_id")
  })
  private Map<VC, P> pricing = new LinkedHashMap<>();

  ...
}
```

The `pricing` maps key

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "v_c")
public class VC implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId private VCId vcId;
}
```

and its (VC) composite key

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class VCId implements Serializable {

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "p_c")
  private PC pC;

  @Column(name = "c_id")
  private String cId;
}
```

the pricing map's value

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
@Entity
@Table(name = "p")
public class P implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId private PId pId;
}
```

and its (P) key

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class PId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "a")
  private BigDecimal a; // complains about this field

  @Column(name = "d_a")
  private BigDecimal dA; // and will probably complain about this one too
}
```

My tables

```
CREATE TABLE b
(
    name   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE v_c
(
    p_c   TEXT         NOT NULL,
    c_id  VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (p_c, c_id)
);

CREATE TABLE p
(
    a       NUMERIC      NOT NULL,
    d_a     NUMERIC      NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,

    PRIMARY KEY (a, d_a)
);

CREATE TABLE b_p
(
    b_name     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    p_c        TEXT         NOT NULL,
    c_id       VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    a          NUMERIC      NOT NULL,
    d_a        NUMERIC      NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,

    PRIMARY KEY (b_name, p_c, c_id),
    
    FOREIGN KEY (b_name) REFERENCES b (name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (p_c, c_id) REFERENCES v_c (p_c, c_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (a, d_a) REFERENCES p (a, d_a) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I made the following changes and it worked:

Replaced the composite ids for `p` and `v_c` with auto increment ids AND added another new, auto increment field called `pricing_p_id` in my `b_p` table:

```
CREATE TABLE v_c
(
    vc_id               BIGSERIAL    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    p_c   TEXT          NOT NULL,
    coin_id             VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE p
(
    p_id                BIGSERIAL    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    a                   NUMERIC      NOT NULL,
    d_a                 NUMERIC      NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    vc_id               BIGSERIAL,

    FOREIGN KEY (vc_id) REFERENCES v_c(vc_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE b_p
(
    b_name              VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    vc_id               BIGSERIAL       NOT NULL,
    pricing_p_id        BIGSERIAL       NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (b_name, vc_id, pricing_p_id),

    FOREIGN KEY (b_name) REFERENCES b (name) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (vc_id) REFERENCES v_c (vc_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (pricing_p_id) REFERENCES p (p_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

and then updated the mapping for the pricing field to only look like this:

```
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "vc_id") // this
  private Map<VC, P> pricing = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```